# IBM Websphere MQ Latency for storing persistent messages .NET client

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

When MQ server receives Put() request, what factors are affecting when messages are stored? Below is potential factors:

1) caching messages in memory for some times, or

2) when certain number of messages are received

3) When certain byte threshold of messages are received

4) MQ server save it IMMEDIATELY for each message.

**UPDATE**

That is, when Put() returns, has messages been saved to hard disk, or in cache depending on factors above?

Any information and links to official doc would be great appreciated.

Below is a simple scenario where Put() is used.

```
     void PutMessages()
    {
         Open(ConnectionMode.Write);

            // putting messages continuously
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMsgs; i++)
            {
                PutMessage(GetMessageInBytes(i));
            }

            queue.Close();
            queueManager.Disconnect();          
    }

    void PutMessage(byte[] messageString)
    {

        // creating a message object
        message = new MQMessage();
        message.Write(messageString);
        message.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        message.CharacterSet = 1208;// IbmUtf8Encoding;
        message.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;

        var options = new MQPutMessageOptions
        {
            Options = false ? MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT : MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT
        };

        queue.Put(message, options);            

    }

    public void Open(ConnectionMode connectionMode)
    {
        var connectionSettings = new Hashtable
        {
            {MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
            {MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT }
        };

        int openOptions = 0;

        switch (connectionMode)
        {
            case ConnectionMode.Read:
                openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                break;
            case ConnectionMode.Write:
                openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                break;
        }
        queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);
        queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
    }


    public enum ConnectionMode
    {
        Read,
        Write
    }
```

Comment: Persistent messages are always written to disk before the PUT returns to the application. Persistent means the message is persisted to disk. If the put is done under sync point then the write to disk happens at the time of the COMMIT rather than the PUT and if the COMMIT returns this means the data has been written to disk. MQ is of course relying on the underlying OS and storage to accurately report that data has been written to disk and it makes use OS provided write functions that are meant to ensure data is not cached in memory. #1 - #3 on your list play no part in persistent messages.

Comment: I want to find out the latency of persistent message. It could be that after PUT returns, messages might have been saved to cache for a few milliseconds before storing to hard disk. I cannot find document on this from IBM.

Comment: If the message is persistent the put will only return once MQ has assured it was written to disk, for instance on linux MQ opens the file with `O_DIRECT` flag.  Outside of MQ control the OS may say it was written to disk and not actually do it, or the underlying SAN storage array might say it was written to disk and not do it, but in those cases the OS and the storage array are normally caching in battery backed  up memory, where they know there is enough power to get the cache flushed to disk in the event of a power failure, but all of this is outside of MQ control.

Comment: The reason I ask is that it might delay a few milliseconds to save messages to avoid performance hit via MQ server logic, instead of saving every message. This happens to RabbitMq. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546274/rabbitmq-latency-for-persistence-messages-via-net-client

Comment: IBM MQ does not do this.  I'm trying to find you a reference to link to, but IBM has always maintained that it is assured message delivery and that it waits until the write is committed to disk before the PUT  (or COMMIT) call returning to the app.  if the app gets a good response then it was written.

Comment: Comparing to IBM MQ, RabbitMQ has better documentation online, even IBM MQ has longer history, in my opinion.

Comment: Pingpong, did you find my answer helpful?  If so please accept it, and if you really appreciated it please vote it up.  If you need more information please let me know what i did not address.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks, I will do it, and mark it if it is.

Comment: Pingpong, I noted your reply on June 1st but did not see any further questions/comments from you or the answer being accepted, let me know if I can further help you with this or if there is something lacking in my answer.

Comment: Pingpong, wanted to check back if you had any further questions about this?

Answer (score 0):

In the IBM MQ v9 Knowledge center page "[Application design and performance considerations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023850_.htm)" it has this two say:

> ### Put persistent messages under syncpoint
>
> Persistent messages should be put and got under syncpoint. This is
>   because when getting a persistent message outside of syncpoint, if the
>   get fails, there is no way for the application to know whether the
>   message has been got from the queue or not, and whether, if the
>   message has been got, then it has also been lost. When getting
>   persistent messages under syncpoint, if anything fails, the
>   transaction is rolled back and the persistent message is not lost
>   because it is still on the queue. Similarly, when putting persistent
>   messages, put them under syncpoint. Another reason for putting and
>   getting persistent messages under syncpoint is that the persistent
>   message code in IBM MQ is heavily optimized for syncpoint. So putting
>   and getting persistent messages under syncpoint is faster than putting
>   and getting persistent messages outside of syncpoint.
>
> However, it is faster to put and get non-persistent messages outside
>   of syncpoint because the nonpersistent code in IBM MQ is optimized for
>   being outside of syncpoint. **Putting and getting persistent messages
>   go at disk speeds *because the persistent message is persisted to
>   disk.*** However, putting and getting non-persistent messages go at
>   CPU speeds because there is no disk write involved, not even when
>   using syncpoint.
>
> If an application is getting messages and does not know in advance
>   whether they are persistent or not, the GMO option
>   MQGMO_SYNCPOINT_IF_PERSISTENT can be used.

---

Chris Frank from IBM gave a presentation at [Capitalware's MQ Technical Conference v2.0.1.6](http://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2016.html) titled 
[More Mysteries of the IBM MQ Distributed Logger](http://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2016/MQTC_v2016_More_Mysteries_of_the_IBM_MQ_Logger_final.pdf), 
Slide "What if I Don’t Use Transactions? (2)" on Page 87 states:

> - Contrast this with not using Syncpoint:
>
>   - Each MQPut will result in at least one physical write to the log file
>
>     - The putting application will be blocked during this time